# Configurar mutiplos dominios para o mesmo site (arquivos diferentes) IIS WS2012

Tags: windows, dns, iis-7, iis

Tenho um site que atende a múltiplas empresas. Porem o domínio é o mesmo.
Foi adquirido dois novos domínios para resolver esse problemas mas o site será mantido mo mesmo servidor IIS.

Agora, o que não consigo fazer é o seguinte:

hoje eu tenho o domínio:

```
www.empresa1.com.br/empresa1.aspx
www.empresa1.com.br/empresa2.aspx
www.empresa1.com.br/empresa3.aspx
```

O que quero fazer é deixar um dominio apontando diretamente para a pagina aspx de cada uma, ou seja:

```
www.empresa1.com.br/ -> Redireciona para: /empresa1.aspx
www.empresa2.com.br/ -> Redireciona para: /empresa2.aspx
www.empresa3.com.br/ -> Redireciona para: /empresa3.aspx
```

Alguem sabe como configurar isso no IIS? (Windows Server 2012)